# How to create a form that uses "=" instead of "&" with HTTP GET?

Tags: forms

We have a form:

```
<form name=input action=https://www.foo.com method=get>
<input type=hidden name=foobar>
<input type=hidden name=ticket>
<input type=text value=bar>
<input type=submit value=IN>
</form>
```

then in the end we will get:

```
foobar=&ticket=
```

but we need

```
foobar=ticket=
```

...what is the syntax for creating an HTML form that will put "=" instead of "&" in given places?

Comment: `foobar=ticket=` - is that `=` at the end significant? That is presumably separating name/value pairs if you want to "use = instead of &"? Or is this intended to be part of the value?

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of this? That could help

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input type=hidden name=foobar>
<input type=hidden name=ticket>
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" name="foobar" value="ticket"/>
```

The bit after the `=` is the parameter's value, so this is saying "submit a parameter called *foobar* with the value *ticket*."

Comment: it will create "foobar&ticket="

Comment: No it won't, it will return foobar=ticket.  The & separates submitted fields.  foobar and ticket are a single field name/value pair in my suggested update.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/HUJpM/

Comment: whops, sorry, yer, I tested it, it's almost good: but it uses "%3D" and not "=" :D

Comment: Are you meaning you want to send an "=" *as* part of your value or name (as opposed to it being the character which links the two)?  If so, you can't do that, as = is a reserved character in a URL - it has to be sent encoded, ie as %3D. - http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html

Answer (score 0):

The `&` comes from the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `enctype` of the form, which is the default.  The other options available are described in the [HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#appropriate-form-encoding-algorithm), but the short story is that the encoding you want is not possible with a standard HTML form.

If Javascript is an option, you could try overriding the submission process and read the form values, building your own string according to your requirements, and direct the browser to the resulting URL.

I have a feeling this problem would be better solved by making the server at the "action" URL take the parameters in the standard `&` way, though...